# Full specializtion of a template function for a template return value

Tags: templates, c++11

Suppose I have a template function like this:

```
template <typename Key>
Key foo(const string &name);
```

I know that for specializing a template function we must fully specialize it like this:

```
template<>
int foo<int>(const string &name);
```

But now I'm looking for a way to specialize this function for a template object, something like this:

```
template<>
Bar<Key> foo<Bar<Key>>(const string &name);
```

I think this would not violate any c++11 laws for specialization and function overriding. But still I could not find a way to do this.

I prefer to do not use a class instead a function to able to make partial specialization for implementing this functionality. Do you have any suggestion to implement this function and specialize it for a template return value?

**Edit:**

The function that I mentioned as an example of specialization has not a valid syntax because it has undefined type `Key`. I just write it to show that there is not a possible solution. If I try to fully defined it as:

```
template<typename Key>
Bar<Key> foo<Bar<Key>>(const string &name);
```

compiler could not compile it because It is assumed as a partial specialization function.

Comment: Why specialize? Can't you overload it?

Comment: The input parameter is same in all functions. How can I overload it?

Comment: what type of error(s) are you getting exactly?

Comment: I don't think `foo<Bar<Key>>` is a full specialization. Is `Key` a non-template class?

Comment: The code I wrote is wrong because `Key` was not defined. It was just an example to show it is impossible. If I use something like this: `template<typename Key> Bar<Key> foo<Bar<Key>> (const string &name);` g++ told me that `function template partial specialization foo<Bar<Key>> is not allowed`

Comment: So, you are not actually doing full specialization, but a partial one. As such, it is not allowed for function templates.

Comment: As a workaround, consider making the return value a reference parameter.

Comment: Why partial specialization? It is fully defined by `Bar<Key>`, for example I can specialize it for all possible type of `Key` and this is valid specialization for compiler. So I think compiler must have a way to interpret this as a full specialization.

Comment: It is a partial specialization for `Key` is unspecified, but a type template parameter.

Comment: It is impossible to return a reference from function, this function parse a string and return an object of a proper type. I do not understand your reason for being partial specialization. Please tell me more details if it is possible.

Comment: What I mean is making your return value into a function parameter that is of a reference type.

Comment: Yes this should work, because this changes to an overloaded function. But I write a program based on this interface and I try to keep this interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of overloading (instead of specializing) `foo` with `enable_if` magic.

```
template <typename Key>
typename std::enable_if<!is_specializaton<Bar, Key>::value, Key>::type
foo(const string &name);

template<typename KeyCont>
typename std::enable_if<is_specializaton<Bar, KeyCont>::value, KeyCont>::type
foo(const string &name);
```

where `is_specialization` may be defined like this:

```
template <template<typename...> class T, typename ... args>
struct is_specializaton {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <template<typename ... > class a, typename ... args >
struct is_specializaton<a, a<args...>> {
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

Comment: It works very well. It was a nicely solution but I changed it a little and I used a template class `is_bar<typename Key>` which indicates this is a bar class or not, because I have another specializations for this function and I think this way makes it easier.